# How can I cross compile the dd linux tool for arm?

Tags: linux, dd, cross-compilation, coreutils

I need to cross-compile a full version of dd because my device only has a busybox one that doesn't support many options. Where do I get the source for it? I've been looking on the kernel repo online but can't find it.

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer the question in your text: you can find the source for `dd` in GNU Coreutils at https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/.

If you need help cross-compiling, please add what device you're targetting, and what distribution you're using to cross-compile...

Comment: Do you mean by using the `--host` option during configuration? What is the best way to compile a single coreutil utility without the need to compile the whole repo?

Comment: @Campa for cross-compilation, yes, “what device you’re targeting” means “what device is specified using `--host`”. To compile a single tool, use standard `make` syntax after running `configure`: *e.g.* `make src/dd` to build only `dd`. (But if you want more detail, please ask a new question.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48911900/cross-compiling-coreutils

Comment: `dd` would probably be available in a package, right? Almost regardless of what Linux they run.

Comment: @Kusalananda given the mention of Busybox, it’s likely that the target is a minimal embedded system, and since it has Busybox `dd`, there’s no guarantee that GNU `dd` is available in an easily-installable form for the device.

Comment: Ah, I missed the fact that they have a `dd` in their busybox. It would have been useful to know what additional features they needed.